# Fill blank cells (Variation)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with filling blank cells of a column.

I have 3 Column headings in A, B, C.

Under that I have variable amounts of rows, but column A and B will always have data.

Column C could have gaps. How could I do something similar to:
Edit > Go To > Special > Blanks, type = in the formula bars, hit the up arrow then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

EXCEPT, with the macro only going up until the last row of A and no further.

I have:

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
    ' Turn off screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Look in column A
    With Columns(3)
        ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        'Convert the formula to a value
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Err.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It however fills right from the bottom of the page and not from where the last "A" value is.

Comment: What do you do if there are cells in the relevant range of column C if the are blank and the only non-blank cell above it is the column header? Reproduce the column header?

Comment: @JohnColeman, because of the way the gaps are being created by a different macro, it will never be the case. Only after the second row can the gaps in C start. It changes the text of certain rows and inserts them below the row that is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use all of Column C -- first determine how far the data in Column A extends and then grab that many cells in column C:

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
    Dim R As Range, n As Long

    n = Range("A:A").Rows.Count
    n = Cells(n, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set R = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(n, 3))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    With R
        ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        'Convert the formula to a value
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Err.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to test for blanks before attempting to put formulas into cells that may not exist.

```
With Columns(3).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)
    If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
        ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
        .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        'Convert the formula to a value
        .Value = .Value
    End If
End With
```