# Select blank cells after a used cell and copy data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem regarding this:

[image]

I need to make the blank cells' value equal to the value of the used cell before them. My desired outcome is this:

[image]

You can observe that the blank cells' value depends on the value of the used cell before them. Is there any way to achieve this using macro? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill blank cells (Variation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382682/fill-blank-cells-variation)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one:

```
Public Sub fillBlank()

    Dim row, lastRow As Integer

    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Getting the last use row.
        lastRow = .Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

        'looping from row 2 to last used row (let row 1 is not blank)
        For row = 2 To lastRow Step 1

            If .Range("C" & row) = "" Then
                .Range("C" & row) = .Range("C" & row - 1)
            End If

        Next row

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer myself after some time.

```
For i = 2 To last

If log.Sheets("Entry").Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then

    If log.Sheets("Entry").Cells(i + 1, 3) = "" Then

        log.Sheets("Entry").Cells(i + 1, 3) = log.Sheets("Entry").Cells(i, 3)

    End If

End If

Next i
```